# When sending a Patch request to my API, getUpdate Handler throws a validation error for a field required in in the schema

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, keystonejs

// The code below works but I'm not happy with it. Without the shown fix it throws a validation error.

```
exports.update = function(req,res) {

    List.model.findById(req.params.id).exec(function(err, item) {

        if (err) return res.apiError('database error', err);
        if (!item) return res.apiError('not found');
```

//Here i have tried PATCH and POST

```
        var data = (req.method == 'PATCH') ? req.body : req.query;
```

//I added this line to poorly fix the bug.

```
        if (!data.email) {
            data.email = item.email
        }
```

// getUpdateHandler is throwing the error

```
        item.getUpdateHandler(req).process(data, function(err) {
```

//This is my postman request

```
/api/item/update/58814243317de2ce8d8090fd
```

//This is my error when removing the fix above

```
{
  "error": "create error",
   "detail": {
       "message": "Validation failed",
       "name": "ValidatorError",
       "errors": {
            "email": {
                "name": "ValidatorError",
                "path": "email",
                "message": "Email is required",
                "type": "required"
            }
       }
   }
}
```

// Update. My issue: I was not passing the required values to the form when setting up the layout on the get req. So values that were not being updated were being posted as null. If it was a required field it raised an error. Fixed

Answer (score 0):

You can give the update handler a list of fields to process by passing it `options.fields` (see [here](https://github.com/keystonejs/keystone/blob/master/lib/updateHandler.js#L21)). So perhaps you could determine which fields have been sent through in the request, and tell the update handler to only process those fields?